# Best way to implement convenient login without password in Android app? (client-server architecture)

Tags: android, authentication, google-signin, google-smartlockpasswords

I'm writing an android app that is a client of a multi-player game.

I need a reliable way to authenticate users in order to connect users with their game account, store their in-game progress and allow them to re-login later and continue playing just where they left off.

An easy solution would be to implement a password-based login and manage passwords all "by myself" (in my app and game server). However, typing passwords on a mobile device is quite inconvenient. [Reading up on the topic](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/77068/what-is-the-best-practice-for-login-in-sign-up-android-application), they say the best login is a login without password prompt (and generally as little user interaction as possible).

I would expect that the best way to achieve a solid passwordless login in an android app is a google account based login. Every android device is connected with a google account already, right?

Searching around the web and stackoverflow, I was extremely surprised that I was unable to find good documentation about my problem, which I thought to be a standard problem that many must have faced before me.

Some things that look pomising to me:

1. [Google Sign-In Api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)
2. [Use Google Smart Lock to sign in with a google account](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials) (Is this in any way better than sign-in api?)
3. Use Google Smart Lock to automatically create my own login/password credentials and use them "behing the scenes"

**So, what ist the best way to implement a convenient login without password?**

My definition of "best" in that context is:

1. Most convenient to the user. As little interaction as possible.
2. Reasonably secure to prevent account highjacking.

Comment: I have found this question from 2013, which is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858828/implement-google-login-in-android-client-server-app?rq=1
The answer there basically says google sign-in api.

Comment: Some you might want to take a look at depending on your needs:
Google Play Games (Gamer ID  - https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin ), Firebase Auth (a managed backend - https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ ), or just go with Google Sign-In (if you manage backend yourself: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/ ). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you need to identify your users. If email address is enough, you are probably looking for OpenID Connect. You will get a signed ID token, if the signature checks out, you can trust the info inside, which includes Gmail address. Google has libraries to make this easy, and Android devices already have a token, so users don't have to enter a password. 
More info here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app

[Google Games login](https://developers.google.com/games/services) could be a better fit for you, and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) makes it easier to manage user data without running your own servers.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far, although a bit short - thank you! What bothers me about Google Games Login as well as Google Sign-In is that these come with a dependency to a huge library that considerably increases the size of my app. OpenID is a good alternative in that regard, because it can be implemented with pure http without too much hassle, as I understand it.

Comment: You should be able to use AccountManager to get a token, and then do the rest in HTTP/JSON. Verifying OpenID tokens could be tricky, but Google has (had?) an introspection endpoint that would parse and validate the token for you at the cost of one extra request.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my app and found that the best solution is to implement the [FIDO protocol](https://fidoalliance.org/how-fido-works/) which allows users to sign-in using a private key stored securely in their mobile device:

> During registration with an online service, the user’s client device creates a new key pair. It retains the private key and registers the public key with the online service. Authentication is done by the client device proving possession of the private key to the service by signing a challenge.

To visualize it, [here's an explanation with a graph of how FIDO works](https://docs.cotter.app/v/0.1.0/features/passwordless-login#how-its-secure).

**Why is this the best solution?**

1. It's very convenient because your users don't need to do any interaction to log in as long as your app is accessed from the device that holds the private key. You can authenticate them silently from the app. If the user is accessing the app from a different phone, you can send a push notif and show a prompt in your app to approve the login request.
2. This method is secure because:

   - It avoids bad passwords from your users.
   - The private key never leaves the device. This means you never need to store passwords in your database.
   - The asymmetric cryptography ensures that only the device that holds the private key can make a valid signature.

**How to implement it in Android:**

For an Android app, the easiest way to implement this is to use [Cotter](https://www.cotter.app/), an authentication service like Firebase but focusing on passwordless login. You can make a free account to get your API keys.

**Documentation:** [This is the guide on implementing the FIDO protocol above for Android](https://docs.cotter.app/v/0.1.0/sdk-reference/android/android-sdk).

If you'd like to do it yourself, you can check out the [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore).

Comment: This is a great answer and I think FIDO can indeed be a good solution to the problem. I kindly ask for your understanding that despite of the quality and effort of your answer I do not confirm it as a solution. That is because I think Google Sign-In, Google Games Login and potentially other ways need to be at least mentioned as valid alternatives too.

Comment: @Putri Karunina Cotter is interesting, but it doesn't seem to implement FIDO, just registration/signing with key protected by by biometric. Or I am missing smth?